# Ajax Refresh of Div on form submit oscommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh, oscommerce

In oscommerce I want to refresh the product div called 'left-div' with form field checked results on autosubmit- rather than whole page:-
I use oscommerce 2.3.4:-
Step wise I have below files-
I have pulled a form on index.php in a div called 'right-div', 
which is called from a box module bm_form.php using below code-

```
    if (class_exists(bm_form)) {
$boxdata = new bm_form;
echo $boxdata->getData();
}
```

Now this form has below code for action on bm_form.php:-

```
<form name="form_srch" id="form_srch" action="'.tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT).'" method="get" >.....</form>
```

The form is processed at this folder

```
 ext/form/form.php
 ext/form/form.js
 ext/form/form.css
```

The above form process is called in my index.php using below code:-
at very top

```
require('includes/application_top.php');
   require('ext/form/form.php');
```

The issue is I when I fill the form it triggers the entire page to refresh whereas I need to refresh only the div with form result.

My form.js uses below code for submit

```
 $("#form_srch").submit();  // submit form
```

I tried using the idea given here for ajax refresh of Div-
[Refreshing ajax div with form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247259/refreshing-ajax-div-with-form-data)

Editing this code in ext/form/form.js:-

```
 $("#form_srch").submit(
            function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
            $.get('ext/form/form.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                $('#left-div').html(data);
            }
);            

           return false;
});  // submit form
```

**And removed the action part from the form leaving action=""**

**But still it does not work at all the form stops working altogether,**
Please can someone help me get this working......

Comment: is your form getting refreshed after submit??

Comment: Yes the whole page refreshes with the form and parsed content.....

Comment: refreshing in the sense, is the page gettting loaded??

Comment: Yes, It loads again with the filtered products :-
I check a checkbox field of the form and it reloads the page automatically with the filtered products.

Comment: but if you are using ajax, page shuld not reload.

Comment: That is it ... This was the case currently without ajax, But when I applied above ajax code and made the action on form as ="" , The form stops working completely....
Ajax does not seem to work

Comment: check for errors in console once.

Comment: I checked using Firebug after adding above ajax, on selecting a field on the form it stops doing anything at all....Firebug  Network and Console both blank....

Comment: tel me wen you want to call ajax?? in click of submit??

Comment: No automatically without click.... As soon as a any parameter is selected

Comment: click?? where?? on click of what you want ajax??

Comment: As soon as I check a field on form the left div refreshes with content using ajax.... currently my index.php refreshes completely to display the parsed filtered content in div.

Comment: first tel me on click of what you want to call ajax??

Comment: Not click button
On  $("#form_srch").submit(                    ......   Here ajax follows

Comment: on submit?? you want rite??

Comment: Yes! I want it this way...

Comment: So on click of submit button, ajax is not firing??

Comment: The form auto submits via form.js ......as soon as a checkbox is clicked in index.php.  It works perfectly without ajax the page reloads with parsed content.  I want that only the div reloads when submit is fired by form.js

Comment: ok ok.., `alert(data)` in ajax and see what is coming..

Comment: `left-div` id is present how many times in your page??

Comment: I am trying to achieve a complete working like I saw here .... http://www.entrale.com/index.php?cPath=7203_6101   When you click on any form part the div with products refresh automatically.....The ajax refresh part is getting me all messed up

Comment: left-div is present once on index.php and once in form.js

Comment: i think y have div twice in your page.

Comment: One is 'right-div' which has the form and 'left-div' which has the products

Comment: what is alert showing??

Comment: Again its not working even alert is not showing up.... :(

Comment: do one thing, you have a submit button?? add id to that and use that in ajax instead on form submit, change to button click

Comment: No I do not have a submit button to it......

Comment: Did you see the link any idea how is it working there????

Comment: ha ha, then how will u submit the form?? that's y its not working, let everything be same. just add a submit button.

Comment: I said before..... the form auto submits via form.js ......as soon as a checkbox is clicked in index.php. It works perfectly without ajax the page reloads with parsed content. I want that only the div reloads when submit is fired by form.js

Comment: show that form.js code?? is that a library or your file??

Comment: I think I am able to figure out the problem, When ajax is used in form.js the action on form at index.php is left blank action="" ,....hence it stops working as none of the process is being called. As without ajax the form has action="index.php"

Comment: The form.js sends data at end without ajax- using $("#form_srch").submit(); ...... at the end of the js file.

Comment: But I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue....

Comment: take action i some global variable and pass to ajax.

Comment: It is not passing it.... Is it possible that we set the form action on index.php to some external php file... Which in turn passes the querystring from the form to form.js so as the query string could be appended to index.php hence then ajax can work and refresh the div?

Comment: you can do that, but not a good practice... just try once...

Comment: The issue is I do not have an idea on how to implement it.....

Comment: U know form action rite Just add that in Ajax n try once...

Comment: Hi, I tried again still does not work....

Comment: Is there a way we could connect the form action with a file that sends an xhr request to fetch the form.php... and then update the div?